# Show images from binding on top of each other

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'd like to show a couple of images as a background of my app. Their opacity is changing dynamicly. I'd love to use binding but I can't seem to find a way to show items from itemssource on top of each other, not in a ListBox or Panorama. My "images" are objects of a very simple class Background, they only contain url to an image and Opacity which I'm changing in code-behind. Every image should take all screen space.

```
<SomeContainer ItemsSource ="{Binding backgrounds}">
            <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="{Binding Opacity}" Source="{Binding url, Converter={StaticResource imageCacheConverter}}"/>
</SomeContainer>
```

Any ideas which container should I use? Do you see any other way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Use an `ItemsControl` and specify an `ItemsPanelTemplate` of something that allows items to overlap, such as `Canvas` or `Grid`

Comment: from what I understand, an `ItemsPanelTemplate` of `Grid` is what you want.